# Exchange no longer working after upgrading to Froyo

Tags: email, htc-desire, exchange

I have a HTC Desire that was on 2.1 and worked perfectly with my works exchange server.
But since upgrading to 2.2 I cannot get it to work at all. There are no errors it just synchs forever.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is an issue with the Exchange Server certificates and Froyo. I have found a few others with the same issue:

- [Exchange 2007 doesn't work after ota 2.2 update](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=1c0798093a0d5569&hl=en)
- [Android 2.2, FRF91 now Active-sync is unable to connect to server, all was fine on Android 2.1](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=6915dc30533e81d2&hl=en)

Those links have several workarounds that *might* solve your problem as long as you can get your IT team to help figure out what is going on.

I have seen several people mention the the [Touchdown](http://www.nitrodesk.com/default.aspx) ([appbrain link](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.nitrodesk.touchdownpro)) app is not having any problems. Touchdown is an alternative to the built-in Exchange sync. It might be the easiest solution for you - though it is a paid app - $19.99 as of right now.

QR Code for the app market:

[image: Touchdown]