# Exchange Inbox Doesn't Sync

Tags: sync, email, exchange

I am using the default mail client exchange.  The client syncs all folders except my Inbox.  It synced one time on Jan 10 when I set it up and that was the only successful sync.  All other Exchange folders are syncing ok.  I just don't get it.  There was a google hit suggesting reducing the size of one's inbox, but mine is small -- a dozen messages?

Manually syncing the Inbox also does not work.

- OS: 2.2
- Phone: HTC Incredible

What other information can I provide?  Any advice?

Comment: Is this question related? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/237/exchange-no-longer-working-after-upgrading-to-froyo

Comment: I wouldn't think so since the phone came with 2.2 and it worked the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the account and re-added it.  It's syncing again.  Not much of an answer, I suppose...

Comment: Hey, if it works for you it'll probably work for someone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After deleting a large (3 MB) message it synced the Inbox again ... maybe this would work for you too?